# How to append results from multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, singlestore

I have 3 tables in singlestore (Memsql) that I want to query and have the results appended.

**Orders**

| part_number | received_qty | update_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| partA | 10 | Monday |

**PullSheet**

| part_number | pull_qty | return_qty | pull_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| partA | 3 | 0 | Tuesday |

**VarianceSheet**

| part_number | pull_qty | return_qty | pull_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| partA | 1 | 2 | Wednesday |

I would like a stored procedure that takes a part_number, limit, and offset input. Query these tables for part_number return all the results sorted by their timestamps and then apply limit and offset. Result should be like below.

**Result**

| event_name | part_number | received_qty | pull_qty | return_qty | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order | partA | 10 | null | null | Monday |
| pullsheet | partA | null | 3 | 0 | Tuesday |
| variancesheet | partA | null | 1 | 2 | Wednesday |

What would be the best way to achieve this? I looked into Unions but that requires the tables to have the same number of columns. That is not the case for my tables.

Comment: You can `UNION` and just use `null` as fillers when needed to get the same number of columns. For example, `select 1, 2 from... union select 1, null from...`

Comment: instead of three table why not save all in one table, as sou need anyway, the rest can you extract from that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table schema is fixed and not going to be changed, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  'order' as event_name
  ,part_number
  ,received_qty
  ,NULL as pull_qty
  ,NULL as return_qty
  ,update_ts as date
FROM Orders

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'pullsheet' as event_name
  ,part_number
  ,NULL as received_qty
  ,pull_qty
  ,return_qty
  ,pull_date as date
FROM PullSheet

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'variancesheet' as event_name
  ,part_number
  ,NULL as received_qty
  ,pull_qty
  ,return_qty
  ,pull_date as date
FROM VarianceSheet
```

Using UNION ALL here for fast performance as there is no need to check for duplicity (event_name will be distinct for each table at least)